# Oracle SQL Developer Spool function is limiting my output?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with SQL right now and I am trying to write a bit of code that pulls a section of data from a database and saves it off to a file. This particular section of code is usually formatted all on one line and about 22,000-23,000 characters long on average. I can already pull some of the code but the pull stops after 4002 characters. My current code looks something like this:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET LONG 100000
SET WRAP OFF
SPOOL output.txt
    Select ________ (my select statement already works on its own);
    SPOOL OFF;
```

I don't know the SQL language at all, I'm looking for some direction as to what functions I could research to help me out?

My end goal with this code is to be able to enter a value in, then have my code use that value to pull a value from one database. From there use both values to pull a long string of code from another database, would this kind of thing be possible in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
SET SERVEROUPUT ON SIZE 1000000
```

I would really suggest that you try and view the SQLPlus Help.

It's really useful, and will explain all parameters to you, which is very useful.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer set

> Tools > Preferences >> Navigate to Database > Worksheet > Max rows to print in a script(**Increase number**)

[image]